# Argparse Positional arguments inside an Optional argument

Tags: python, mysql, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want the following structure with argparse :

```
usage: ms1.py [-h] [-c] [-u] [password] [DB_name]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c, --c               show available items
  -u password DB_name,  Update database
```

I wish to place -h -c -u all as optional.
but if -u was declared by user - password & DB_name must be positional to it.

What is the right code ? (I'm so confused by the documentation, many thanks)

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--c', required=False)
p.add_argument('--u', required=False)
p.add_argument('password')
p.add_argument('db_name')
args = p.parse_args()
print(args)
```

You don't need to have `-h`. `argparse` does it for you at no extra cost.

`c` and `u` are optional and `password`, `db_name` are required and the position matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true', help='show available items')
parser.add_argument('-u', nargs=2, metavar=('password', 'DB_name'), help='Update database')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

samples:

```
1442:~/mypy$ python3 stack62967549.py -h
usage: stack62967549.py [-h] [-c] [-u password DB_name]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -c                   show available items
  -u password DB_name  Update database
1442:~/mypy$ python3 stack62967549.py -c
Namespace(c=True, u=None)
1443:~/mypy$ python3 stack62967549.py -u foobar FOO
Namespace(c=False, u=['foobar', 'FOO'])
```